# How would I make it so if any number bigger than 10 or less than 10 it would say "wrong answer"?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to make a code so if the answer is less than 10 or more than 10 it says "wrong answer" I just testing somethings right now I'm very new to coding.
right now I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "log.h"

int main()
{
    MultiplyAndLog2(5, 2); // this is what is going to be multiplied
    
    int x = 11;

    if (x == 10) // I have it so I if it equal to 10 it says right answer
        Log("right answer");
    
    if (x == )  // Heres where im stuck I dont know what to add if any number other than 10 is the answer
        Log("wrong answer");    
    
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Heres my log.h its a bit messy...

```
#pragma once

int Multiply(int a, int b, int c) // this is so I can multiply 3 integers at a time just for testing.
        {
            return a * b * c;
        }

int Multiply(int a, int b) // this is the same thing but for 2 integers at a time
{
    return a * b;
}

void MultiplyAndLog(int a, int b, int c) // this is so that whatever 3 integers are multiplied it would say answer: and then the answer to the question
{
    int result = Multiply(a, b, c);
    std::cout << "answer:" << result << std::endl;
}

void MultiplyAndLog2(int a, int b) // this is so that is 2 integers are multiplied it would say answer: and then the answer to the question
{
    int result = Multiply(a, b);
    std::cout << "answer:" << result << std::endl;
}

void Log(const char* message)  // This is so if I type Log I can write whatever I want for example "right answer"
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you,
Mario

Comment: `if (x != 10)`, or use an `else`.

Comment: "This is so if I type Log I can write whatever I want for example "right answer"" Note that it is `std::cout << whatever << "\n";` that allows you to print whatever, while your `Log` function only works with `const char*`s it cannot (easily) log a number for example. I see you are learning and practicing, though one of the next steps should be to understand that not everything must be hidden behind a function, especially when a function already exists. Also `a*b;` is simpler to write and read compared to `Multiply(a,b);`

Comment: Also note that functions that are not inlined nor templated shouldn't be defined in headers because defining them in headers may lead to multiple-definition error when the header is used from multiple translation units. Only declarations should be in headers and definition should be another source file (`.cpp`) for normal functions.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I didnt know that I thought they were different thanks for telling a*b is simpler.

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT I will work on that. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `!=` operator to check if two values are not equal:

```
if (x != 10)
    Log("wrong answer");
```

Another way is using `!` operator to negate the logic:

```
if (!(x == 10))
    Log("wrong answer");
```

You can also directly code "if the answer is less than 10 or more than 10":

```
if (x < 10 || x > 10)
    Log("wrong answer");
```

Or better way:

```
if (x == 10) {
    Log("right answer");
} else {
    Log("wrong answer");
}
```